# PHP $_GET[] Mod Rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite

I've made a website, and page links are formed like this: `?page=projects_project1`.
I want the pages to be accessible this way as well: `projects/project1`. So `?page=` should be removed, and `_` should be replaced by `/`... So what's being accessed now using `?page=projects_project1`, should become accessible at `projects/project1`...
What do I need to put in my `.htaccess` file to achieve this? Please also explain how it is done, so I can do it myself next time.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([a-z0-9_]+)$ index.php?page=$1_$2 [NC,L]
```

The first line says that it should follow the symbolic links that may exist, the second line actually switches on the `RewriteEngine` and the third matches links that look like the following:

`anything_except_a_forward_slash/anything_here_that_is_an_alphanumeric_or_forward_slash`

Comment: ... That didn't go too well... `Internal Server Error`.

Comment: Ooops, forgot one of the important keywords - fixed!

Comment: Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS): There are too many redirects.

Comment: It seems like something is keeping your redirects from ending. Are you manually redirecting in the file that serves your pages?

Comment: If `$_GET['page']` is empty: `header('Location: ?pagina=home');`. Can that possibly be the problem?

Comment: Well, is `$_GET['page']` supposed to be the same as the `$_GET['pagina']`? If so, there's your problem (as you're using both right now). Otherwise, I'm not too sure what's going wrong.

Comment: Yeah, it is :p So, now I know what's the problem... but how to solve it? :p

Comment: Well, you have to make sure you're only using either `$_GET['page']` or `$_GET['pagina']` (ie: `?page=` or `?pagina=`), and then update the `.htaccess` with the chosen `GET`-variable.

Comment: ... I'm only using $_GET['pagina'];

Comment: Well, if you're certain that you're `ONLY` using `pagina`, then change `page` to `pagina` in your `.htaccess`. Hope that resolves it. :)

Comment: ... I'm going blind xD I didn't see that it said `page` in stead of `pagina` xD

Comment: This doesn't look too well either xD http://www.heuvel-folie-serres.com/Veestal_v2/foliestallen/projecten

Comment: That's because you need to set the `<base>`-tag in your `<head></head>`. <base href="http://www.heuvel-folie-serres.com/Veestal_v2" /" />` should be the correct base. :)

Comment: ... Wich messes up every page in stead of only the ones with slashes in their URLs...

Comment: Well, I'm setting my `href` as `http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . 'SUBDIR HERE (IF ANY)';`, and it works on all my pages (rewritten as well as normal ones).